# Fetch data from MySql from table as main category and the other as subcategory

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Information:

I have two tables 
1. grading_main
2. grading_sub

grading_main

```
+-------------+-------------------+
|   g_main_id |    g_main_name    |
+-------------+-------------------+
|           1 | Responsibilities  |
|           2 | Skills            |
|           3 | Efforts           |
+-------------+-------------------+
```

grading_sub

```
+-------------+---------------+--------------------+
|   g_sub_id  |   g_sub_name  |  main_element_id   |
+-------------+---------------+--------------------+
|           1 | Quality       | 1                  |
|           2 | Treatment     | 1                  |
|           3 | Equipment     | 2                  |
+-------------+---------------+--------------------+
```

I use this code to join them together

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM grading_sub s JOIN grading_main m ON s.main_element_id = m.g_main_id";
```

what I want to do like this:

Fetch: 
g_main_name (the name of element) as header

and fetch the Sub elements as check boxes

sample: output

```
+-------------+----------------+-----------------------+
|   g_main_id |   g_main_name  |  g_sub_name           |
+-------------+----------------+-----------------------+
|           1 |Responsibilities| checkbox() Quality    |
|             |                | checkbox() Treatment  |
+-------------+---------------+------------------------+

+-------------+---------------+------------------------+
|   g_main_id |   g_main_name |  g_sub_name            |
+-------------+---------------+------------------------+
|           1 |   Skills      | checkbox() Equipment   |
|             |               |                        |
+-------------+---------------+------------------------+
```

I used this code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM grading_sub s JOIN grading_main m ON s.main_element_id = m.g_main_id";
$run = mysqli_query($DBcon,$sql);
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)){
    echo '
        <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 with-margin">
               '.$rows['g_main_name'].'
             </div>                                             
        </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 with-margin"> 
                    <input type="checkbox" class="flat" name="sub_elements[]" value="'.$rows['g_sub_id'].'"> '.$rows['g_sub_name'].'
                </div>
            ' ;

}
```

The result like this:

```
+-------------+----------------+-----------------------+
|   g_main_id |   g_main_name  |  g_sub_name           |
+-------------+----------------+-----------------------+
|           1 |Responsibilities| checkbox() Quality    |
|           1 |Responsibilities| checkbox() Treatment  |
+-------------+----------------+-----------------------+
```

So the Question is I want to fetch g_main_name of table grading_main as header and all g_sub_name of grading_sub table that they joined through main_element_id with g_main_id

Thanks,

Comment: Please add schematics of your table. To make the question more understandable, you can add some example values for the tables, and show us how the values need to be shown in the output.

Comment: Thanks for interest I have made an edit to make the question more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost: +1 for improving the question by adding tables and samples!

If I understand correctly, you want to show one header, followed by X checkboxes belonging to that header.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM grading_sub s JOIN grading_main m ON s.main_element_id = m.g_main_id";
$run = mysqli_query( $DBcon, $sql );

// First obtain all data and store it in an array.
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $run ) ) {
    $data[ $row['g_main_name'] ][] = $row;
}


// Now use two loops to loop over the array.
// The first one loops over the headers
foreach( $data AS $g_main_name => $subItems ) {
    echo '
        <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 with-margin">
               ' . $g_main_name . '
             </div>                                             
        </div>';
    foreach( $subItems AS $item ) {
    echo '
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 with-margin"> 
                <input type="checkbox" class="flat" name="sub_elements[]" value="' . $item['g_sub_id'] . '"> '. $item['g_sub_name'] . '
            </div>';
}   }
```

note: untested code. I hope you get the idea.